# (When) is Firefox 3.6 going to be pushed to 3.5.x users?

Tags: firefox, updates

Is it a separate branch entirely?  So 3.6 will never automatically come to 3.5.x users?

(It's not that I'm too lazy to click through the help menu.  I actually don't want it to for now because it breaks an older intranet app of ours that we don't have time to fix at the moment.)

If it will, when, and is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of 3.5 do you have? Because, if you have the latest version 3.5.8 of the 3.5 branch, you should get the invitation to download the version 3.6:

More information [**here**](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Upgrading+to+Firefox+3.6#Upgrading_from_Firefox_3_0_x_or_3_5_x) from Mozilla:

> Once you have the latest Firefox 3.0 or 3.5 update, use Help > Check for Updates...  again, to upgrade to Firefox 3.6.

Comment: 3.5.8.  It's true (although it wasn't when 3.6 first came out) that if you manually use Help > Check for Updates, it appears.  But I'm wondering when it will, by itself, prompt the user to upgrade, like it did for 3.5.7 to 3.5.8.

Comment: @Kev:   I don't know.  3.0.* has been getting an suggested update all the way to 3.6 as of last weekend.  Dunno when mozilla started doing that; it was on a machine I might not have used FF on in a few months.

Comment: Thanks Snark and Dan Neely, +1 for the information even if it's not an official answer (maybe there isn't one and I won't know until it's too late.)